# UIPageviewcontroller doesn't work to swipe scroll the view for first two time

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uipageviewcontroller

Pageviewcontroller is not working for first two swipe after it is work.I don't know what is the issue in my code. please refer my code below

**PageViewController Coding**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.sampleImage=@[@"sample1.jpeg",@"sample2.jpeg",@"sample3.jpeg"];
self.sampleContent=@[@"sample1",@"sample2",@"sample3"];

self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;


MYViewCtrl *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];

self.pagecontrol= [UIPageControl appearanceWhenContainedIn:[self.pageViewController class], nil];
self.pagecontrol.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:152.0/225.0 green:10.0/225.0 blue:115.0/225.0 alpha:1.0];
self.pagecontrol.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:121.0/255.0 green:121.0/255.0 blue:121.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];


self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.myview.frame.size.width, self.myview.frame.size.height+35);
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

[self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
[self.myview addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];


}
- (MYViewCtrl *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
if (([self.sampleImage count] == 0) || (index >= [self.sampleImage count])) {
return nil;
}


MYViewCtrl *childViewController = [[MYViewCtrl alloc] initWithNibName:@"MYViewCtrl" bundle:nil];
childViewController.Image = self.sampleImage[index];
childViewController.Content = self.sampleContent[index];
childViewController.pageIndex=index;
return childViewController;

}-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController          viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
NSUInteger index = ((MYViewCtrl*) viewController).pageIndex;

if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
    return nil;
}

index--;
return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
NSUInteger index = ((MYViewCtrl*) viewController).pageIndex;

if (index == NSNotFound) {
    return nil;
}

index++;
if (index == [self.sampleImage count]) {
    return nil;
}
return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
-(NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController{
 return [self.sampleImage count];
}
-(NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: remove if (index == NSNotFound) {
    return nil;
}
from viewControllerAfterViewController 
 and try once

Comment: @PoojaManiklalBohora am tried but its not working

Comment: - (MYViewCtrl *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
if (([self.sampleImage count] == 0) || (index >= [self.sampleImage count])) {
return nil;
}

where is else part?

Comment: @PoojaManiklalBohora this is else part      MYViewCtrl *childViewController = [[MYViewCtrl alloc] initWithNibName:@"MYViewCtrl" bundle:nil];
childViewController.Image = self.sampleImage[index];
childViewController.Content = self.sampleContent[index];
childViewController.pageIndex=index;
return childViewController;